# Generating numbers list in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-3.5

I often need to generate lists of numbers. The intervals can have quite a lot of numbers. I have a method like this:

```
public static int[] GetNumbers(int start, int end)
{
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
        list.Add(i);
    return list.ToArray();
}
```

Is there a way to make it simpler, faster?

I am using .NET 3.5

Answer (score 152, accepted):

This would probably be a bit faster - and it's certainly simpler:

```
int[] values = Enumerable.Range(start, end - start).ToArray();
```

Do you definitely need it as an array though? If you only need to iterate over it, you could just use [`Enumerable.Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) directly, to get an `IEnumerable<int>` which never needs to actually hold all the numbers in memory at the same time.

Comment: My thoughts on this, shouldn't you calculate these values during runtime instead of prefilling an array, since they only represent a sequenced value?

Comment: @Caspar: That's why I mentioned using just `Enumerable.Range`. It really depends on what the OP wants to do with it. For example, he may be passing it to a method that requires a list or array - for example, something to shuffle any array.

Comment: how do I generate something like 1, 5, 10, 15, 20? Anything in-built?